# Как обратиться к переменной каждого из обьектов в массиве?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть массив GameObject. Это 6 точек на карте. В каждом из объектов есть статичная переменная:

```
public static string status = "free"
```

Задача.
Нужно перебрать элементы массива и, если в 1 из элементов массива status != free, сделать какое-либо действие.

```
public GameObject [] locSpawnPointArrey = new GameObject[6];

locSpawnPointArrey = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("HospitalSpawnPoints"); // заполнение массива объектами со сцены
```

Comment: Думаю, если "ВЕЗДЕ" static переменные, то значит не везде... Надеюсь вы понимаете, чем отличаются static переменные от обычных, если нет, то бросьте Юнити и вперед на метанит.

Comment: @HztronsWorld к статическим переменным можно обратиться только через имя класса, и они существуют в единственном экземпляре, общие на всю программу. Если вы в одном месте ее поменяете, то поменяется везде. Делайте обычные переменные.

Answer (score 0):

> Как обратится к переменной каждого из обьектов в массиве?

```
public GameObject [] locSpawnPointArrey = new GameObject[6];

locSpawnPointArrey = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("HospitalSpawnPoints");

foreach (var a in locSpawnPointArrey )
{
     a.NameOfBoolVariable = false;
}
```

Если же это статическая переменная, то она общая для всех обьектов даного класса. И ее можно изменять только обращаясь вот так:

```
NameOfClass.NameOfStaticBoolVariable = false;
```